# primefaces calendar date field not working after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, date, jsf, primefaces

I have a  field in my jsf page.I put a p ajax request that allows me to do a treatment. when i use in first time the picker, it works fine. Once the treatment finished, the slider does not update the date field anymore.
To make it work again, i must close the picker and open it again.
The patern of my field is dd/mm/yy hh:mm.
here is my picker in my jsf page :

```
<p:outputLabel for="datetimeslotStart" value="#{vocabularyBean.localizedMap.lblDateFromEmpty}&#160;:" />
```

does someone already have this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code sorry

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="manualAssignmentsTimeslotPickerStart">
                            <p:outputLabel for="datetimeslotStart" value="#{vocabularyBean.localizedMap.lblDateFromEmpty}&#160;:" />
                            <p:calendar id="datetimeslotStart" value="#{manualAssignmentsBeanAlias.timeslotStart}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" showOn="button" >
                                <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{manualAssignmentsBeanAlias.onDateTimeslotStartSelect}"  update="@(.dialogMain)" />                                   
                            </p:calendar>   
                        </h:panelGrid>
```